# Using jQuery, can you have two external scripts that use the $(document).ready(function()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to split up the jQuery .js file into two, but I have noticed some of the features arent working when I split it up. Is it because I have two external scripts that start with:

$(document).ready(function(){

Is that not possible?

Comment: You might want to describe what isn't working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can have two scripts that both set `$(document).ready(...).`

Answer (score 0):

Whoops, I think I found the answer.

http://docs.jquery.com/Events/ready#fn